# How to split a String JSON format as constructors of an object in Java?

Tags: java, json, constructor

I have a java class `Payment.java` which constructs the "Payment" object with 5 constructors and required setter/getters as following:

```java
    public class Payment {

        //Contractors
        private Double amount, fee;
        private String TXID;
        private int time, type;

        public Payment(Double amount, Double fee, String TXID, int time, int type) {
            this.amount = amount;
            this.fee = fee;
            this.TXID = TXID;
            this.time = time;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public Double getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public void setAmount(Double value) {
            this.amount = value;
        }

        public Double getFee() {
            return fee;
        }

        public void setFee(Double value) {
            this.fee = value;
        }

        public String getTXID() {
            return TXID;
        }

        public void setTXID(String value) {
            this.TXID = value;
        }


        public int getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public void setTime(int value) {
            this.time = value;
        }

        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(int value) {
            this.type = value;
        }

    }
```

I have another method which sends a `HTTP(GET)` request to an external API and returns the results in `JSON` format as a String as shown below:

```
{
  "result" : {
    "nh_wallet" : true,
    "payments" : [
      {
        "amount" : "0.00322253",
        "fee" : "0.00006577",
        "TXID" : "",
        "time" : 1533114558,
        "type" : 1
      },
      {
        "amount" : "0.00273396",
        "fee" : "0.0000558",
        "TXID" : "",
        "time" : 1533029140,
        "type" : 1
      },
      {
        "amount" : "0.00284428",
        "fee" : "0.00005805",
        "TXID" : "",
        "time" : 1532944513,
        "type" : 1
      },
      {
        "amount" : "0.00213709",
        "fee" : "0.00004361",
        "TXID" : "",
        "time" : 1532856970,
        "type" : 1
      }
    ],
    "base64MarchantID" : "366GT4q6hw7cVN6zzkFWfqZeKHHXZCp4rA"
  },
  "method" : "stats.provider.payments"
}
```

Supposing that the JSON result String is actually a dynamic `<List>Payment`, what is the best way to split this String into several splitted "Payment"(s) dynamically?

Comment: just serialise it into a List<Payment> it would fit in correctly, which serialisation library are you using?

Comment: error in your json response

Comment: Error: Parse error on line 1:
"payments": [{  "amount": "0.
----------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'

Comment: your response json is not in proper manner view

Comment: @Ram Mohan dubey : You're right I fixed it
@ Ogbe : java.util.ArrayList & java.util.List I'm not sure if I answered your question. However, which library do you recommend?

Comment: *** AN IMPORTANT REMINDER ***

Obviously the String is containing ALL the JSON format result; but I want only exploit the json fields which matches with constructors (amount, fee, TXID, time, type) that would be another challenge!

Comment: I mostly use retrofit and Asyncktask sometimes